# Does Algolia work with embedded Google Docs

Tags: wordpress, google-docs, algolia

A WordPress site is being developed with the Google Drive Embedder Plugin, they would also like to use Algolia for its search features. Does Algolia search embedded Google Docs?

Answer (score 1):

Algolia doesn't connect to Google Docs automatically, but you could index the embedded Google Docs content manually. This would require some custom development.

For each embedded doc, you would first use Google's API to [download it](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads) into a file, then you would use one of Algolia's [API clients](https://www.algolia.com/doc/) to upload the content of that file into an index.